# Internal Server Error on only one page in magento 2, rest pages are working fine

Tags: magento, magento2

I am facing 'Internal Server Error' on only one page(https://smilzo.co/new.html) in Magento 2 website, rest pages are working fine(https://smilzo.co/about-us).

Even I have set up staging on a subdomain that is working fine(https://smilzo.co/sandbox/new.html).
But main site suddenly started showing  'Internal Server Error' on only one pages.
Please suggest me something to fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the webserver error logs (Apache or NGINX). This is often the only place where useful details are logged when HTTP errors occur.